Unable to determine the serialization information for DateTime
I am trying to run mongoDB query in c#. I need to get records in descending order of UpdatedDate. UpdatedDate is stored in string format e.g. 9/9/2022 9:55:16 PM
var collection1 = _collection
    .Find(searchquery)
    .Sort(Builders<LoanApplication>.Sort.Descending(app => DateTime.Parse(app.UpdatedDate)))
    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Limit(pageSize).ToList();

This query gives me an error

An unexpected error occurred: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the serialization information for app => Convert(Parse(app.UpdatedDate), Object).

How can I get result in descending order of UpdatedDate?

Because the driver doesn't know how to convert DateTime.Parse into query. You should write an aggregate query to perform the conversion. Note that, you shouldn't store the date value as string, this results poor query performance that requires converting the field for all documents before sorting/paginating.

Try use $toDate with aggregation.

Outside it being a string in the first place, that's about the worst possible format to have it in.
